# Unable to establish one or more of the specified browser connections / Ubuntu / Firefox Headless

Tags: node.js, firefox, web-scraping, browser, testcafe

My setup:

OS: Ubuntu 18

Testcafe Version: 1.8.8

Browser: Firefox

I have several Ubuntu servers where Testcafe was working. Due to a security issue, I had to reinstall the servers entirely. Unfortunately in the fresh reinstall, Testcafe is saying it is unable to establish one or more of the specified browser connections.  I have firefox installed and reconfirmed it was installed.

Previously I did this:

1. Issue command: `sudo testcafe test.js`
2. Expected behavior: After a moment, I could visibly see in the logs that the test was running using Firefox headless.  *Life was fine*.

Now when I do the exact same thing in the fresh reinstall:

1. Issue command: `sudo testcafe test.js`
2. Unexpected behavior: After a moment, I get this in console:

`Using locally installed version of TestCafe. ERROR Unable to establish one or more of the specified browser connections. This can be caused by network issues or remote device failure.`

*Bummer!*

Here is the .testcaferc.json I am using:

```
{
    "browsers": ["firefox:headless"],
        "speed": 0.1,
        "skipJsErrors" : true,
        "pageLoadTimeout": 5000
}
```

When I run `testcafe --list-browsers`, I get:
`firefox`

My test file:

```
import { ClientFunction, Selector } from 'testcafe';

fixture `triage`
    .page('https://www.google.com/');

test(`test debugging`, async t => {

await t
    .wait(5000)
        console.log(`I did it!`)

})
```

Previously there was no issue!  Had I not had to reinstall Ubuntu, there would be no fail. I have actually 5 servers like this and really need a fix. Any ideas why this is happening?

I even installed chrome. Same issue! Failure to establish a connection to chrome too.

Comment: I commented this question on GitHub: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/5314#issuecomment-658183985

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally this was solved for me.  My solution, and what I did differently.

Previous install steps:

1. Install Ubuntu
2. Login as root
3. Create new user
4. Login to new user account
5. Install Node.js as sudo in new user account
6. Install Firefox as sudo in new user account
7. Install Testcafe as sudo in new user account
8. Setup git clone of express...

After days of looking at this I thought wait `Unable to establish one or more of the specified browser connections` may just mean `Can't see the browser due to being installed as sudo in a user account thus unable to establish that browser connection`... (like it can't see it for some reason).
To test this theory, I rearranged the install steps and suddenly everything worked!
Here are the steps that solved this issue for me:

1. Install Ubuntu
2. Login as root
3. Install Node.js AS ROOT
4. Install Firefox AS ROOT
5. Install Testcafe AS ROOT (this allows you to do `npm i -g testcafe` as well as being able to issue the command `testcafe "firefox:headless" mytest.js -e` instead of `sudo testcafe "firefox:headless" mytest.js -e`, which doesn't work with sudo well)
6. Create new user
7. Login to new user account
8. Setup git clone of express...

Now all my requests are triggering the tests as before.